# JSON Deserialize Error: The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, json, visual-studio-2015, deserialization

I'm trying to output JSON to a drop down list in a web form. I've managed to get this far:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string getString = client.DownloadString("http://myfeed.com/app_feed.php");

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic item = serializer.Deserialize<object>(getString);
string name = item["title"];

return name;
```

This brings back the feed ok but it runs into an error on the line:

```
string name = item["title"];
```

Bringing back this error:

> Additional information: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

This is a sample of my feed:

```
{"apps":[{"title":"title1","description":"description1"},    
{"title":"title2","description":"description2"},
{"title":"title3","description":"description3"}
```

So I thought that I was referencing the first title and I was planning to loop through them:

```
string name = item["title"];
```

But obviously not! 
I have looked on Stackoverflow but I can't find an answer that I can apply to my own code.

Comment: Only a suggestion: Instead of deserializing your JSON to a `dynamic` object, I would recommend that you create some strongly typed C# classes that you can work with and iterate over. You can use http://json2csharp.com to help you with this, or the built in tool in VS > `Edit` > `Paste Special` > `Paste JSON As Classes` :)

Comment: ']}' missing in the sample feed.  is It the complete feed ?

Comment: I think that's just a typo @Arshad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`title` is inside another key `apps` and its an array so you should iterate it, I show you just select first one using index 0

```
string name = item["apps"][0]["title"];
```

you can access all by foreach

```
foreach (var ap in item["apps"])
{
    Console.WriteLine(ap["title"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your JSON is invalid. Second: you need to loop over your items, as it is an array. If you want to access the first one, you could do: `item["apps"][0]["title"]`

Looping through all items:

```
var str = @"{""apps"":[{""title"":""title1"",""description"":""description1""},    
{""title"":""title2"",""description"":""description2""},
{""title"":""title3"",""description"":""description3""}]}";

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic obj = serializer.Deserialize<object>(str);
foreach (var item in obj["apps"])
{
    Console.WriteLine("item title: " + item["title"]);
}
```